# BIC inconsistencies in R

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-models

I'm running a linear mixed effects model using an lme4 function. I am then using a BIC function to look at whether adding more factors improves model fit.
Now, the way I've done it so far was using the following:
`BIC(model1)`
to get the BIC for each model. But when I run an ANOVA to compare them, the output also gives me the BIC values, among other things, which are slightly different to the ones I get from the BIC function. Neither of them make a lot of sense by the way, because they increase instead of dropping as I add ew factors, but that's a separate issue. Should I be worried about those differences? I'm new to this kind of thing and still trying to understand both R and the mixed effects model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're question is close to being migrated to stats.stachexchange because it is about statistics, not programming. You might want to add a little more context - are your models nested? Are you changing only the fixed effects, or also the random effects?

Comment: In general, different AIC or BIC values from different functions isn't concerning, since they are both calculated up to an additive constant. You should expect the differences to be consistent across functions.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.